# Place a footer row as an header row of a group of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a table like the following :

```
 rfa_yea | rfa_idx |                      rfa_dsp                       | rfa_tpr
---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+---------
 2013    |       1 | PIGATO VERM.NO/ROSS/ORMEASCO CL75                  | A
 2013    |       2 | ESTATE\134134134047 BICCHIERE SING.VERDE           | A
 2013    |       3 | Rif. Trn. N. 17 del 17/04/2013 Cassa N. 00001      | C
 2013    |       4 | BIB.RED BULL LAT.CL25 ENER.DRI                     | A
 2013    |       5 | BIB.RED BULL LAT.CL25 ENER.DRI                     | A
 2013    |       6 | SHOPPER 30X60 MAXI X 1000                          | A
 2013    |       7 | SHOPPER HD 27X50 MEDIE X 1000                      | A
 2013    |       8 | PIGATO VERM.NO/ROSS/ORMEASCO CL75                  | A
 2013    |       9 |  * SCONTO SUBTOTALE                                | A
 2013    |      10 | Rif. Trn. N. 19 del 17/04/2013 Cassa N. 00001      | C
```

The record with the field `rfa_tpr` marked as `'C'` is the header of the group of rows that came before it. I need to place the row as an header of the group of rows instead of footer(separator) as at the moment, so I want to retrieve a result set like the following :

```
 rfa_yea | rfa_idx |                      rfa_dsp                       | rfa_tpr
---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+---------
 2013    |       3 | Rif. Trn. N. 17 del 17/04/2013 Cassa N. 00001      | C
 2013    |       1 | PIGATO VERM.NO/ROSS/ORMEASCO CL75                  | A
 2013    |       2 | ESTATE\134134134047 BICCHIERE SING.VERDE           | A
 2013    |      10 | Rif. Trn. N. 19 del 17/04/2013 Cassa N. 00001      | C
 2013    |       4 | BIB.RED BULL LAT.CL25 ENER.DRI                     | A
 2013    |       5 | BIB.RED BULL LAT.CL25 ENER.DRI                     | A
 2013    |       6 | SHOPPER 30X60 MAXI X 1000                          | A
 2013    |       7 | SHOPPER HD 27X50 MEDIE X 1000                      | A
 2013    |       8 | PIGATO VERM.NO/ROSS/ORMEASCO CL75                  | A
 2013    |       9 |  * SCONTO SUBTOTALE                                | A
```

Is there a solution with only SQL ? The solution should work on each of these kind of database server : MSSQL, PostgreSQL and MySQL.

**Note**

I can have multiple separators(footers) rows, not only two as in the example ...

Comment: Various solutions exist, but they're pretty much all awful. This, along with the difficulty of doing totals rows sanely, is one of those things SQL makes surprisingly difficult.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the group of rows that came before it*"?  Bear in mind that SQL tables do not have an inherent order.  Are you inferring what came "before" and "after" from the data in some way, e.g. from the value of `rfa_idx`?  You would be wise to maintain a column in your table that holds some sort of `group_id`.

Comment: @eggyal take a look at my own answer, i found a solution !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.rfa_yea ,
        a.rfa_idx ,
        a.rfa_dsp ,
        a.rfa_tpr
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 c ON a.rfa_idx <= c.rfa_idx AND c.rfa_tpr = 'C'
GROUP BY  a.rfa_yea ,
        a.rfa_idx ,
        a.rfa_dsp ,
        a.rfa_tpr
ORDER BY MIN(c.rfa_idx), a.rfa_tpr DESC, a.rfa_idx
```

**[SQL Server Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4afc/2)**

**[MySQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6c21/1)**

**[PostgreSQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/89457)**

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by myself, below the SQL query if someone in the future will need to do  something similar  :

```
SELECT * FROM righfatture r 
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT r1.rfa_tpr,r1.rfa_idx, COALESCE(r2.rfa_idx, -1) AS IDXP FROM righfatture r1
LEFT JOIN righfatture r2  ON r2.rfa_idx < r1.rfa_idx AND r2.rfa_tpr = r1.rfa_tpr
WHERE r1.rfa_tpr = 'C'
) j ON j.rfa_tpr = r.rfa_tpr AND r.rfa_idx = j.rfa_idx
ORDER BY CASE WHEN j.rfa_tpr IS NOT NULL THEN  j.IDXP ELSE r.rfa_idx END
```

Comment: This is not really going to work. On above example you'll get row with rfa_idx = 10 on top and then 1,2,3.. through 9. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e424b/2. Altough, idea is fine and small change in the last condition (= instead of >) will make it happen - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e424b/4

Answer (score 1):

Solution is easy, problem is the problem...

Solution under assumption that last year should come first and rfa_idx comes behind rfa_yea.

```
select * from table1 order by rfa_yea desc, find_in_set(rfa_tpr, "C,A"), rfa_idx;
```

Problem is that you should not rely too much on increasing ids and the already mentioned design questions.

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a database design issue. The "groups of rows" you are talking about have nothing in common besides the order of the rows.

I would suggest, adding a field and inserting a common value for these groups of rows, if possible. While this is not a convenient solution, I think a database design *should* reflect the way you want data to be organized.

Comment: Aside from the database design issue that is evident, I'm looking for a solution because it is and interesting riddle ... ;-)

Comment: Technical challenge aside, from a practical standpoint, why would you want to avoid the most natural solution?

Comment: Because of curiosity, take a look at my own answer to my question ... Thanks anyway .